# Amazon Web Service functional form

Tags: php, html, css, database, amazon-web-services

I have compleated the html and css of a website and I intend to host it on AWS. I have two forms on the site(html/css) and I need to make them functional. My php knowlege and database is very basic and I haven't use AWS before. How should I procead about making my froms functional? Is there any prebuild features in AWS that I could use for this purpuse? Perhaps a good tutorial I could fallow.. My forms are very simple and I'm only requesting a few input fields from visitors that I would need to have access to. 
I will really apreciate any advice.

Here is my html:

```
    <form 
    name="submitForm" 
    method="post" 
    id="submitMessageForm"
    onsubmit="return(validate())" 
    action="./index.php?action=submitted" 
    class="form-style">

    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input 
    type="text" 
    id="nameFirst" 
    name="nameFirst" 
    placeholder="Enter Name"/>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input 
    type="text" 
    id="email" 
    name="email" 
    placeholder="Enter Email"/>

    <label for="messageContent">Message:</label>
    <textarea 
    id="messageContent" 
    name="messageContent" 
    rows="7"></textarea>
    <br>

    <input 
    style="padding: 6px !important;"
    class="button"
    type="submit"
    id="submit"
    name="SEND"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: AWS has little affect on how you would solve this problem. For the most part AWS is just like any other server.

Comment: I see. Do you have any suggestions on what I could do to tackle this one giving my skill set. Again I just need to be able to get this info from visitors.

Comment: There are services like Wufoo that will allow you to build a form with very little programming knowledge. The free plan might be enough for what you need. This is a case where, if you don't understand what you are doing, you could create a form that can be used to send spam, or open to injection attacks which can result in your database getting deleted.